# Unable to debug any Roslyn Diagnostic

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm having trouble getting VS2015 RTM to install my diagnostic into the Experimental instance, so that I can debug it.

The Error List contains the following
Severity

```
AD1002  Unable to load Analyzer assembly   C:\USERS\ADAM\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0ROSLYN\EXTENSIONS\ADAM\FSDVBANALYSER.VSIX\1.0.2\FSDVBAnalyser.dll
Could not load file or assembly 'FSDVBAnalyser, Version=1.0.5795.13535, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.  
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The project is available [Here](https://github.com/AdamSpeight2008/FSD).

How can it get it work?

**Added** VS2015 Version Information

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.24627.00 Update 1
>   RC Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01040
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2015 RC   00322-20000-00000-AA613 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015 RC
>
> Visual C# 2015 RC   00322-20000-00000-AA613 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>   RC

**Added** Link to gist of ActivityLog.xml

https://gist.github.com/AdamSpeight2008/40c21f31b9eee94bd23d

Comment: Exactly which version are you refering to? I tried it on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, and it works. (The codefix throws 'System.InvalidOperationException' on line 29.)

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam See updated text.

Comment: Just to mention it here, this issue has been reported to the Roslyn team: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6784

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Update 1 embeds a newer version of Roslyn, try upgrading the Nuget packages to the prerelease ones. Also, to get more information on your issue you could start VS with logging: `devenv.exe /Log`, this will add detailed exception logs to "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Version\ActivityLog.xml"

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've add a link to the gist of activitylog.xml

Answer (score 0):

Per [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6784#issuecomment-157113589) this is just a bug that has been fixed (but the updated build hasn't been released yet.)